# How do I get a simple max-height transition on click to work?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I a trying to have a transition from max-height: 0 to the max-height determined by the content within, through JavaScript.

At the moment it just pops open and close with no transition.  A smooth transition open and close is the desired effect without using jQuery.

Here is a test [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GpNPJB).

```js
var isOpen = false;

function toggle () {
  isOpen = !isOpen;
  var container = document.querySelector('.div-body');

  container.style.maxHeight = 'none';
  var containerHeight = window.getComputedStyle(container).height;
  container.style.maxHeight = 0;

  console.log(containerHeight);
  console.log(isOpen);

  if(isOpen === true) {
    container.style.maxHeight = containerHeight;
  } else {
    container.style.maxHeight = 0;
  }
}
```

```css
.info-card {
  background: #ccc;
  padding:10px 20px;
  width:600px;
}
.div-header {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.div-body {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 300ms ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="info-card">
  <div class="div-header" onclick="toggle()">
    Click
  </div>
  <div class="div-body">
    <div class="inner-body">
      <p>body</p>
      <p>body</p>
      <p>body</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var isOpen = false;
function toggle () {
  isOpen = !isOpen;
    var container = document.querySelector('.div-body');


    var containerHeight = 0;
    if (isOpen) {
      container.style.maxHeight = 'none';
      containerHeight = window.getComputedStyle(container).height;
      container.style.maxHeight = 0;
    }

  console.log(containerHeight);
  console.log(isOpen);
  setImmediate(function() {

    if(isOpen) {
      container.style.maxHeight = containerHeight;
    } else {
      container.style.maxHeight = '0px';
    }
    });
  }
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KdNbZd

Basically, doing things like removing the height restriction to get the computed style make sense, but ultimately it's hard for the browser to figure out the transition when you're changing the style multiple times in one javascript frame. So, I added `setImmediate` to do the transition one frame later (similar to setTimeout(..., 0).

Answer (score 0):

The easy way would be animating from `max-height: 0` to `max-height:auto`, however, apparently it's not possible to do that. We can animate to any valid `max-height` using only CSS, but since you want to use the height of the container we have to rely on javascript to get the desired value.

It's important to mention that you should take care with class selectors like `.div-body`, because they will match every element with that class on the DOM. That could be dangerous in a scenario where you have more than one panel in your page for example.

## Example

```js
function getHeight(elm) {
  var elmStyle = getComputedStyle(elm);
  return parseInt(elmStyle.height) + parseInt(elmStyle.paddingTop) + parseInt(elmStyle.paddingBottom);
}

function toggle(elm) {

  var card = elm.parentNode,
    content = card.querySelector('.panel-content'),
    contentWrapper = content.querySelector('.panel-content-wrapper'),
    contentHeight = getHeight(contentWrapper);

  content.classList.toggle('open');

  if (content.classList.contains('open')) {
    content.style.maxHeight = contentHeight + 'px';
  } else {
    content.style.maxHeight = 0;
  }

}
```

```css
body {
  background: #9BA7B6;
  margin: 25px;
}
.panel {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  width: 400px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
}
.panel-header {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #949494;
  border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;
  background: linear-gradient(#D9D9D9, #B1B1B1);
}
.panel-content {
  background: #EDEDED;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height .5s;
  border-radius: 0 0 6px 6px;
}
.panel-content-wrapper {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel">

  <div class="panel-header" onclick="toggle(this)">Panel header (click to toggle)</div>

  <div class="panel-content">

    <div class="panel-content-wrapper">

      <div>this is my panel content</div>
      <div>this is my panel content</div>
      <div>this is my panel content</div>
      <div>this is my panel content</div>

    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```